# Multiple Lat/Long Coordinates to Miles

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude

I have a few x,y coordinates that I wanted to get the area of. I figured the best course of action is to convert the X,Y decimal coordinates into nautical miles and then do the area of a polygon. I've googled around, but really haven't found anything helpful for my problem. Not looking for the answer, but I just wanted to know how to approach this and what to potentially use for the conversion.

These are the coordinates that are in an array:

```
    Lat_Long = [60.8427194, -042.7969500; ...

                60.8646972, -042.5323889; ...

                60.7640417, -042.5178639; ...

                60.5882139, -042.8185056; ...

                60.8080111, -042.8507500; ...

                60.8069889, -042.8374167; ...

                60.8083028, -042.8278361; ...

                60.8114056, -042.8186167; ...

                60.8152306, -042.8117389; ...

                60.8203694, -042.8055667; ...

                60.8256528, -042.8013611; ...

                60.8315167, -042.7985083; ...

                60.8374056, -042.797078; ...

                60.8427194, -042.7969500];
```

Comment: Maybe consider [`areaint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/areaint.html)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Comment: I tried areaint and polyarea: Areaint gave me 1.0363e-06 and polyarea gave me .0556

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `areaint`? Do you understand what the returned number means?

Comment: "Not looking for the answer": Then you probably [shouldn't have asked the question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @dasdingonesin I was implying that I wasn't just posting this because I didn't want to put the effort in. I know the answer to it, but I want to see if I can mimic my results on MATLAB.  I just don't know how to approach it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the diameter of the area of is not more than a few kilometers (or miles if you insist) then

1) transform the coordinates to x,y space with unit meters
2) Use the simple formula `areaint`

for 1): convert lat and long which are in unit degrees to meters, by multiplying with a factor

```
f = 40 000 000 / 360. // or use a more exact value using the WGS84 equitorial radius
```

(Circum fence of earth in meters divied by 360 degrees)

so

```
x = longitude * f;
y = latitdue * f
```

addionally multiply x with the cos(averageLatitude), this eliminates the fact that lat and lon have not the same scale (on equator the distance between two degrees of longitude is aproxx 111km, while on the north pole it is 0.

```
x= x * cos(toRadians(averageLatitude));
```

The result is the area in square meters.

The averageLatitude is the mean value of all latitude coordinates of that area